# How to delete all elements only that i want?

Tags: python, list

I'm really beginer of python and i'm wondering how to remove all same elements that i want

I know i can remove a one element with list.remove('target') but it just happen once,

I googled about it but they just say use 'for' or 'while' but i don't know how to do it with a smart way

example ,  when i have list "apple" i want to make it "ale" with parameter'p'

I tried

```
list = ['a','p','p','l','e']
    for i in list:
       list.remove('p')
```

but i got error that 'ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list'

(My English might sucks because i'm Korean :( and it's my first ask in stackoverflow )

Comment: use a diff variable name instead of `list` since it's a buitlin datastruc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it)

Comment: Um, i thank you for answering but i tired changing name right now that 'list' to 'myList' but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

First you should not be using list as a variable name as list is a built-in type in python.

See: [Built-in types in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists)

For your question, you can use list comprehension for this.
eg:

```
my_list = ['a','p','p','l','e']
element_to_remove = 'p'
new_list = [item for item in my_list if item != element_to_remove]
# new_list = ['a', 'l', 'e']
```

Comment: Thank you for answer my question!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list to set (so that there will be no repetitions) and convert it back to list. After, remove the element you want.

```
my_list = ['a','p','p','l','e']
my_list2 = my_list(set(my_list))
my_list.remove('p')
```

Comment: I believe this would remove any duplicate element. It works in this particular case, but is not a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try list comprehension:

```
[i for i in l if i not in ('p',)]
```

where l is your list.

Comment: What a perfact way! Thank you for answer my question!